# How to know when Vue component has finished initializing completely?

Tags: vue.js

So, in my Vue component there is asynchronous `created` method and there are several variables with asynchronous watchers. Those variables are used as `v-model`s by some elements in `template` section of a component. Watchers call other methods which change values of those variables.

This goes on for some time (several hundreds milliseconds) until all data has been initialized and no variable is changed anymore. Now, I have some code which must run when all variables have their initial values defined. But the problem is, how do I know when all code in the component has finished executing?

Sure, I could run my code at the end of the `created` method, but since some elements in the `template` section are updating variables they use as `v-models` those watcers run independently of the `created` method, and `created` method is finished much before watchers are. Even `mounted` method exits before watchers do. So, I can not just put my code at the end of the `created` method.

So, my question is, how to run some code **at the very end of the component initialization?** So, after `created` method and after all watchers which are run when value of the variables changes have finished? I am only talking about the initial run of the watchers which is caused by the change in the `v-model` which is caused by the initialization of the elements in the `script` section here, not about the watcher executions later in the lifetime of the component. So, I need to run it after elements in the `script` section have finished initialization and watchers related to their `v-model` variables have finished execution.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array of boolean flags, for however many things you need to watch.  They are all initialized in a single array as false, and each watcher is in charge of setting a different index to true. Once all watchers have run, all the flags are true *and by watching that array* you can tell when everything has been initialized.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      initialized: [false, false],
      watch1: null,
      watch2: null,
      isDone: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    watch1(newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        this.initialized[0] = true
      }
    },
    watch2(newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        this.initialized[1] = true
      }
    },
    initialized: {
      handler: function (newVal) {
        if (newVal.every(i => i)) {
          this.isDone = true // initialization is completely done
        }
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.watch1 = 'some value1'
    }, 2000)

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.watch2 = 'some value2'
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). In Promise, you can wait for multiple values to return, and then return all the arrived values.

In your code:

```js
function getDefaultValue() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    // first interface
    const first = await first()

    // second interface
    const second = await second()
 
    ......

    resolve({first, second, ...})
  })
}
```

use:

```
getDefaultValue().then(({first, second, ...}) => {})
```